# Trying to reconcile absolute position UL with left float

Tags: html, css, position

I'm brand new to coding, and realize there is probably a very simple solution to my problem. I have imported Photoshop slices into Dreamweaver by using absolute positioning for each slice within a **DIV #container** (which is how I have been instructed by my professor.)

http://s1292.photobucket.com/user/ajp2487/media/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-10%20at%209.04.27%20AM_zpsbaeyzcdf.png.html

I want to create a horizontal navigation via CSS (blue text) over the placeholder slice (light gray text). To do so, I created an **DIV ul li** for the links.

http://i1292.photobucket.com/albums/b578/ajp2487/ss_zpswqnc75pl.png~original

I realize that you supposedly cannot float an element when absolute positioning is in play. However, when I remove absolute positioning, try relative positiong, etc. from **.nav, ul**, the **ul** disappears (probably behind the slices) and shifts my existing slices. When I do use absolute positioning, the float left command is rendered useless. Right now everything is as it should be, except that I need the **ul** to flow horizontally, not vertically!

There has to be an simple solution to this; I'm ready to tear my hair out and any help would be appreciated. Please answer in as simple terms as possible!

Answer (score 0):

display: inline-block; will also do the job if you cannot use floats. Does it not work if you put the float on the li?

```
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is an example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xboPxB

Another few things to note (though I completely understand the requirements of using Dreamweaver and doing things in a bizarre way due to coursework), position: absolute; can be dangerous and layout breaking, as I'm sure you are discovering; though I won't go into this unless you have any questions as you mention it is due to your instructor.

Line-height should really be unitless - think of it as line-height * font size. If your font size is 20px (or 1em) and line-height needs to come out as 40px (or 2em), then line-height is 2.

I hope I've understood and answered your question correctly! Please let me know if you are still stuck :)

Comment: Holy smokes, yes, putting float on the li does work. I thought I had tried every possible combination. O_o  Can I hug you? (P.s. yes, I know absolute positioning is not ideal...)

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it was helpful :) could you possibly accept this answer then as correct if your problems are sorted as it will close the issue? Thanks